# запись в запущенный exe

Tags: windows, файлы, io

Добрый день!
Возникла необходимость, сохранять параметры запуска программы в собственном exe файле.
Попытки открыть обычными методами типа fopen или _open не увенчались успехом.
Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность писать в уже запущенный exe?

Answer (score 2):

Никак.

На время выполнения файл заблокирован. Хуже того, в нормальных обстоятельствах он будет в `Program Files`, в защищённом от записи каталоге.

Если вы пишете на C#, используйте [`Settings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx). Если нет, возможно, в вашем языке есть фреймворк для такого. В любом случае, хорошая, вежливая программа должна писать только в `%APPDATA%`.

Comment: Вежливая программа может писАть ещё и в HKCU - кстати, это и попроще будет.

Comment: @Akina: Ну, писать в реестр вроде уже как-то не модно

Comment: @Akina: Хотя конечно тоже хороший вариант, да.